# Frequency of apparition

Tags: c++

I try to solve a problem and i can't find a solution. The problem is about lexicographical ordering of  words from a text, and to show the frequency of apparition of each words. I succeded to arrange the words and i don't have any ideea about the second part of the exercise. Here is my code :

```
void lexigografic(char *s)
{
 char *p, cuv[20][20], aux[20];
 int i=0, n, j;
 p=strtok(s, " ");


while(p)
{
    i++;

    strcpy(cuv[i], p);
    p=strtok(NULL, " ");
}
n=i;
for(i=1; i<n; i++)
    for(j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
    if(strcmp(cuv[i], cuv[j])>0)
{
    strcpy(aux, cuv[i]);
    strcpy(cuv[i], cuv[j]);
    strcpy(cuv[j], aux);

}


for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
{
     if(cuv[i] == cuv[j] )
     fout<<cuv[i]<<"***";

     fout<<endl;
}

}
```

Comment: What does this mean: **frequency of apparition**?  Do you mean the frequency of occurrence of each word?

Comment: Yes, they are synonymous, i guess..

Comment: See my answer below using a `std::map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `std::map`.  It will keep it's keys sorted.  Here's a code snippet:

```
std::map<std::string, int> m;  // definition of map
std::string = "word";  // sample word

m[s] += 1;  // increments word count of string; inserts it if it doesn't exist.
```

Comment: The fact is that I don't know anything about maps, i didn't learn yet.. :( there is no other choice?

Comment: Are you prevented from using them? Or do you just need to learn about them?  If it's the latter, just read up on them here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/.  That single line of code literally takes care of everything.